# Google OAuth callback phase executed twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've been stuck on this issue for a couple of days, and i am a loss here. I have implemented the google login via OAuth 2 for our website, it's working perfectly on my computer (local environment) on any browser, but when i deploy to our staging environment, it works only with google chrome. We use the **devise 2.2.8** gem to handle authentification coupled with ***google-oauth2 0.2.6*** to handle interaction with google login. One of the thing that concerns me is that our authentification process happen on 2 different subdomain such as:

1. Landing on webpage (en.mywebsite.com)
2. Click on Login with Gmail
3. Request made to our server
4. Redirection on google consent screen
5. Callback url for authentification (my.website.com)

Once the user is authentified, he will only browse on my.website.com but originally before being authentified he was on a different subdomain. So i was wondering if there could be some issue on a session level during the authentification ?

Here are the log when i want to authentify myself via Google Login on our staging environment on google chrome:

> Jul 16 11:36:44 (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
>
> Jul 16 11:36:44 (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
>
> Jul 16 11:36:45 method=GET path=/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
>   format=html controller=authentification/omniauth action=google_oauth2
>   status=302 duration=49.96 view=0.00 location=http://my.website.com/
>   params={"state"=>"e6a565c411170cfcbc62d0209970bd39842aae090671a95a",
>   "code"=>"4/Ib0zrAHgAVNWli9RwJsXf9g7edcVlx96xVLmxCB4Eoc",
>   "controller"=>"authentification/omniauth", "action"=>"google_oauth2"}
>
> Jul 16 11:36:46 method=GET path=/ format=html controller=my/dashboard
>   action=index status=200 duration=839.57 view=160.90
>   params={"controller"=>"my/dashboard", "action"=>"index"}

---

Here are the log when i want to authentify myself via Google Login on our staging environment on Safari:

> Jul 16 11:24:21 (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
>
> Jul 16 11:24:22 (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
>
> Jul 16 11:24:23 method=GET path=/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback
>   format=html controller=authentification/omniauth action=google_oauth2
>   status=401 duration=0.77 view=0.00
>   params={"state"=>"05e6567e2443eb5766c77a271d60a767a568b32491ce852c",
>   "code"=>"4/yNlgCDyI71mmYoT48BpWIJNnbaKzUhy7bclIxGHqJdo",
>   "controller"=>"authentification/omniauth", "action"=>"google_oauth2"}
>
> Jul 16 11:24:23 (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
>
> Jul 16 11:24:23 (google_oauth2) Authentication failure!
>   invalid_credentials:  OAuth2::Error, invalid_grant: Code was already
>   redeemed.
>
> Jul 16 11:24:23 { Jul 16 11:24:23   "error" : "invalid_grant", Jul 16
>   11:24:23   "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed." Jul 16
>   11:24:23 }

Because the callback phase is initiated twice, and the token from google oauth is for a uniq usage, the second callback obviously fails.

I have one file omniauth.rb file under initialiser folders, to place Omniauth in the middleware stack:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, "google-id", "secret", { scope: "email, profile, gmail.readonly, calendar"}
end
```

I know some people got the same issue as me when they defined Omniauth twice because they defined it in both omniauth.rb file and devise.rb so i made sure it defined only once.

Comment: I was running into this issue because OmniAuth was once registered as a Rack handler and once inside Rails - so it still got called twice. That's at least what happened when  I ran into this issue a few months ago.

Comment: When you run rake middleware you could see 2 OmniAuth? What concerns me is that's it is working on a local environment.

Comment: Oh then it may be an issue with your NGINX/Apache Proxy? I had this happen to me once on another occasion where NGInx was sending every request twice to the Backend. I don't remember the exact reason any more but that caused some headaches back then. Hope this helps.